# While read line per column but use full line too

Tags: shell

I need to work on my file per line. I first want to print the first two columns and then use the full line as an input for a program:

```
column1\tcolumn2\tcolumn3\tcolumn4
```

I have the following:

```
while read -r a b c ;
do
    echo $a":"$b
    program -I input;
done < file.txt
```

I have tried to add `$a"\t"$b"\t"$c"\t"$d"` as input but it does not work.

Comment: What do you expect to happen and what's actually happening?

Comment: My script is printing the value of two columns correctly ($a":"$b) but I cannot find a wait to print the whole line and ask the program to read this single line as an input file. The program failed because it is reading the "\t" as string and not as separator.